# Why call copy constuctor 3 times with std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

My code is here, i can't get why there are 3 times call of copy constructor...

```cpp
struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    int age;
    Person(std::string name, int age) : name(name), age(age){
        std::cout << "some constructor" << std::endl;
    };
    Person(const Person& person) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
        name = person.name;
        age = person.age;
    };
};


void print_person(Person person)
{
    std::cout << "in print_person" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    std::cout << "in print_person, person = " << person.name << ", " << person.age << std::endl;
}

int test()
{
    std::thread ta(print_person, std::move(Person("zjp", 12)));
    ta.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}

int main()
{
    test();
    std::cout << "test have finished" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    return 0;
}
```

and stdout

```sh
some constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
in print_person
test have finished
in print_person, person = zjp, 12
```

Why called copy constuctor 3 times?
I can only know 2 of them~
emmmm thanks
thanks
thank

Comment: The `#include`s are missing from you example code.

Comment: `void print_person(Person person)` a copy is made when you enter this function. Why don't you use `const Perso&` as the parameter type?

Comment: Furthermore, you have create a copy ctor but not a move ctor. Hence, I guess the copy ctor is used to move the object.

Comment: Last but not least, I get this when I execute your code:

```
some constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
in print_person
test have finished
in print_person, person = zjp, 12
```

That's 2 copies, not 3.

What is your compiler?

Comment: Note that strictly speaking the code shown exhibits undefined behaviour since `test` is declared to return an `int` but contains no `return` statement.

Comment: Do you still get 3 copy ctor calls if you declare `test` `void` instead?  `void test()`